# Bloquear popup do navegador mobile ao pressionar elemento da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, navegador-de-internet

**Descrição:**

Um amigo esta desenvolvendo uma aplicação em que é acessado uma página web e ao interagir com os elementos é enviado para um arquivo `PHP` comandos para manipular um robô com o `Arduino`. Por enquanto estamos fazendo apenas ligar os leds, é feito o seguinte utilizando os eventos do `jQuery`:

1. **mousedown touchstart**: Para ligar o led quando estiver com o mouse pressionado sobre o elemento usando um navegador desktop e mobile.
2. **mouseup touchend**: Para desligar o led quando não estiver com o mouse pressionado sobre o elemento usando um navegador desktop e mobile.

**Problema:**

No navegador mobile, seja o Chrome ou Firefox, ao deixar pressionado por alguns segundos aparece a popup para executar uma ação com o navegador, mas quero apenas que faça o ligar/desligar do led e o aparecimento dessa popup esta atrapalhando na hora de desligar o led.

**Procedimento correto**

Não aparecer a popup e permitir desligar o led.

**Anexos**

[image: Popup Chrome]

Comment: dentro da função, você certamente tem a variável do evento, comumente chamada de `e` .
Poderia tentar, em primeiro lugar, adicionar `e.preventDefault();`e verificar se o "problema" ainda ocorre.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido adicionando o seguinte bloco `CSS`:

```
img {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: Isso só vai funcionar com navegadores que usam o webkit. Vocês vão realmente utilizar só esses?